# I want to receive command line input while receiving command line output

Tags: go

I am currently creating a small command line chatroom app in Go, I was wondering if there was anyway i could receive command line input on a separate line (Where the user types messages to be sent) while receiving command line output (messages from other users)

Comment: You might want to consider the use of a library like https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui which has been used for apps such as console IRC client.

Comment: Use goroutines to read concurrently from the terminal and network connections.